# Quiero que la fecha se ponga encima del primer mensaje si es un día nuevo y no en cada mensaje del chat

Tags: java, android

Quiero poner la fecha en mi chat, pero solo una vez si es un día nuevo la fecha tiene que ponerse allí encima del primer mensaje mandado, pero lo que tengo ahora es que se me está poniendo la fecha encima de cada mensaje.

Quiero que sólo aparezca una sola vez como se puede observar en la mayoría de las aplicaciones, si es un día nuevo y los demás mensajes no tienen que tener la fecha.

De momento me está saliendo así... Si es necesario puedo subir mi xml también o POJO, pero creo que el código que tengo que arreglar va aquí.

Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**MessageAdapter**

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
    private static final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 1;

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Chat> mChat;
    private String imageurl;

    public MessageAdapter(Context mContext, List<Chat> mChat, String imageurl) {
        this.mChat = mChat;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == MSG_TYPE_RIGHT) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_right, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_left, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Chat chat = mChat.get(position);

        holder.show_message.setText(chat.getMessage());
        if (imageurl.equals("default")) {
            holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(imageurl).into(holder.profile_image);
        }

        if (position == mChat.size() - 1) {
            if (chat.isIsseen()) {
                holder.text_seen.setText("Seen");
            } else {
                holder.text_seen.setText("Delivered");
            }
        } else {
            holder.text_seen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.message_time.setText(chat.getTime());
        holder.date.setText(chat.getDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mChat.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView show_message, text_seen, message_time, date;
        ImageView profile_image;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            show_message = view.findViewById(R.id.show_message);
            profile_image = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            text_seen = view.findViewById(R.id.text_seen);
            message_time = view.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
            date = view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (mChat.get(position).getSender().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
            return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
        } else {
            return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Crea un nuevo `viewType` como `MSG_DATE_DIVIDER`. Crea el layout para mostrarlo como deberías. Inserta un objeto en tu lista `mChat` (esto debe ser antes de notificarle los cambios al adapter o asignarle una lista) con alguna propiedad booleana para ver si es un divider (cada vez que se produzca un cambio de fecha). Luego en `getItemViewType` haces el if para detectar si es un `MSG_DATE_DIVIDER`. Deberias tener algo como `if(mChat.get(position).isDivider()) return MSG_DATE_DIVIDER;` así te evitas sobrecargar esas vistas en viewTypes donde no las vas a utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar el valor, si este es igual al que se mostró anteriormente evitas que se muestre la vista.

```
if(!holder.date.getText().toString().equals(chat.getDate())){ //Es diferente, se muestra
   holder.date.setText(chat.getDate());
   holder.date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{  //No se muestra y esconde la vista.
    holder.date.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
}
```

Comment: No me ha funcionado, me siguen saliendo las fechas encima de cada mensaje como se ve en la foto de arriba.